# how to create a struct and pass to a new thread via pthread_create()

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

I have a callback function I am writing where I need to:

1 create a struct
2 create a new thread and pass this struct to the thread for it's exclusive use
3 return a pointer to this struct ... from the callback function ... to the main program.

This will allow communications through shared memory between the original program and the new threads.

I assume I have to use malloc since the scope of a struct created in the callback function is only in the function.

I can't make it static because I will create multiple threads each with their own personal struct.

I need to understand the process since I am a newbie.

Would it work this way?

1 malloc a chunk of memory "sizeof" the struct.
2 pass the pointer to this chunk to the new thread and return it to the main program.
3 once in the new thread make a new struct using this memory?

I have searched for a week now and can't see how this should be done.

BTW: I cannot modify the main program which is single threaded by design.
I can only make this callback function to spawn one of many new threads and communicate thru this shared memory which I would like to be a struct.

Thanks.

```
struct myStruct
{
    int elem1;
    int elem2;
    int elem3;
};



int* callBack(some parameters)
{
    *p = malloc(sizeof(myStruct));

    result = pthead_create( ??, ??, void *(*newThread), *p);

    return p;
}


void newThread()
{
    // pull off *p from stack?

    // somehow use the declared struct to access the malloc mem

    p->elem1 = p->elem2 + p->elem3;
}
```

Comment: I am confused. Do you want heap (malloced) memory or do you want shared memory (and if you need shared memory, why?)

Comment: I want whatever works. All I have seen are malloc examples so I assume this is what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Threads created through `pthread_create()` take in a `void*` as their argument, so the prototype of your thread routine should be as follows:

```
void newThread(void* data)
```

This `void*` then corresponds to the pointer passed as the final argument to `pthread_create`. You can then cast this pointer to the appropriate data type (but make sure you get the right one!). An example is as follows:

```
void newThread(void* data)
{
    struct myStruct* p = data;
    p->elem1 = p->elem2 + p->elem3;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your Help Slugonamission !!  I am not sure I understand the line:         struct myStruct* p = data;

Comment: That casts the void pointer to a pointer of the correct type. pthreads doesn't know what data type you want to pass, hence uses a void pointer instead to specify the lack of any type information. To use it, you therefore have to cast it back to the correct type again.

Comment: so 'p' is a local variable, also a pointer, to a type specifically myStruct?

Comment: Yes. The pointer itself stores the address of the object being pointed to, so there's two different pointers both pointing to the same data.

Comment: I still have a problem ... the memory that the thread sees is not the memory that the outer process sees.  Something must be wrong in the way that I am passing the arg pointer?  If I understand correctly pthread_create() wants a pointer to the arg and will pass this pointer to the thread?

Comment: ... or does it want a pointer which is passed unchanged to the new thread as a pointer to void?